# Insert row in CakePHP not from a form

Tags: cakephp

I am fairly new to CakePHP. I am trying to insert a row into a model/table but not from a form.

I want to insert static values so I have the following inside my controller's action

```
$this->save( 
    array(
        'name' => 'dummyvalue1',
         'price' => 0.00,
         'contract' => 'dummyvalue2',
         'points' => 0
        )
    );
```

However no record is inserted and a blank page is displayed, my view does not render so I presume some error is being swallowed somewhere.

In short how can I insert a row to a model/table but not from a form submission?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change `$this->save` to `$this->ModelName->save` in your controller method.

```
$this->ModelName->save( 
    array(
        'name' => 'dummyvalue1',
         'price' => 0.00,
         'contract' => 'dummyvalue2',
         'points' => 0
        )
    );
```

**[Check Manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->loadModel('ModelName');
$data = array ('ModelName' => array('name' => 'dummyvalue1',
                                    'price' => 0.00,
                                    'name' => '',
                                    'contract' => 'dummyvalue2',
                                    'points' => 0));

$this->ModelName->create($data);
$this->ModelName->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your data in an array.

```
$this->data["ModelName"]['name'] = 'dummyvalue1';
$this->data["ModelName"]['price'] = '0.00';
$this->data["ModelName"]['contract'] = 'dummyvalue2';
$this->data["ModelName"]['points'] = '0';

$this->ModelName->save($this->data["ModelName"], false);
```